# CallContext – value disappears - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and .Net

I’ve come upon a somewhat peculiar problem. I have a C# solution with two projects. One is a standard WPF application, the other a WPF User Control library. The WPF application project is the startup project.
In each project I have one window. In the startup project I open the window and set a value in the logical call context by using `CallContext.LogicalSetData`. This is done on load. I then close the window and open the window in the WPF User Control library. I populate one textbox with the value in the logical call context (using `CallContext.LogicalGetData`) and this works fine. 
I have a button, which on click fires an event that populates another textbox with the same value from the logical call context – but all of a sudden this value is null.

I can make it work simply by changing the starting window to not do it’s “thing” on load but rather on a button event.

The startup window code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("test", "value set onload");
        TestWindow win = new TestWindow();
        win.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("test", "value set on button event");
        TestWindow win = new TestWindow();
        win.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, if I comment out the four lines in the `OnLoaded` method then it works fine.

The other window:

```
    public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PreLoadedText.Text = CallContext.LogicalGetData("test") as string;
    }

    private void GetValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string eventTextText = CallContext.LogicalGetData("test") as string;
        EventText.Text = eventTextText ?? "The value is null";
    }
}
```

Btw. I tried using the `AsyncLocal<T>` class - but I just experienced the same problem.

Example solution can be found here:
[Visual studio solution as zip file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8eWqG9yKLanei1zZ215THprYWs)

Note - I'm not looking for a workaround (I have a couple), I'm looking for a reason why this happens.

Comment: Maybe it's a threading issure? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Call context? You sure the word "call" is not important? I am not 100% familiar with all the nuances of the CallContext but the button click is not in the same call stack as the form constructor.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes - I'm sure. When using the CallContext class methods above it should store the value independent of call stack and across threads. Perhaps though I'm using setting the value in a sub-thread or in a sibling thread to the one that handles the final button event, which would cause this problem. For more info on CallContext: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html

Comment: It's because the instance of `Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext`, which contains the `DataStore` of the `CallContext`, changes between the calls. You can check that if you give by using "Make Object ID" in the Visual Studio debugger. Why does this happen? I have absolutely no idea. I tried to debug the .net Framework source without any luck. As far as `AsyncLocal<T>` is concerned: It also uses the same `CurrentThread.ExecutionContext` and thus suffers from the same problem. It doesn't happen if you use `ThreadLocal<T>` because that's using `[ThreadStatic]` and the `Thread` doesn't change.

Comment: @haindl - you should put it as an answer so I can accept it. I use quite some async methods so using ThreadStatic attribute is not an option.

Comment: Thank you for offering to accept it! :-) I wasn't sure if that would be enough information to qualify as an accepted answer.

Comment: I can duplicate this by just calling `LogicalSetData` in the constructor and `LogicalGetData` in the button click (it gets `null`). I'm also not sure why, but looking at the different call stacks, the initial construction/Loaded event code has a `Dispatcher.WndProcHook` that goes through `MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run`. Sounds suspiciously like the culprit, there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the instance of `Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext`, which contains the `DataStore` of the `CallContext`, changes between the calls. You can check that if you give it a marker by using "Make Object ID" in the Visual Studio debugger.

Why does this happen? I have absolutely no idea. I tried to debug the .net Framework source without any luck.

As far as `AsyncLocal<T>` is concerned: It also uses the same `Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContext` and thus suffers from the same problem.

It doesn't happen if you use `ThreadLocal<T>` because that's using `[ThreadStatic]` and the `Thread` itself doesn't change.

Comment: This answers my question, but doesn't solve my problem. Since it seems like a bug I've registered it as such:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3107023/callcontext-logicalsetdata-value-disappears

Comment: @Ykok I'm very curious what the official answer from Microsoft will be. Maybe you should also include a link to this question here or attach your VS solution directly to the bug because it's probably much easier to reproduce for Microsoft if they actually have some code.

Comment: I've included a link. I also tried to upload the solution, but apparently I'm unable to attach anything to the bug (tried with a small png as well).